# Angularjs changes image src to “unsafe:” in node webkit application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-webkit

I am working on a AngularJS NodeWebkit application and adding image src as following

```html
<div ng-repeat="product in product.productList" >
<img class="product-image" ng-src="images/product-{{product.id}}.png" alt="image" with='50' height='50'  />
</div>
```

It is coming good in web browser but when it is coming in node webkit application the src is appending with 'unsafe'. eg:-

```html
<img class="product-image" ng-src="/images/product-24586.png" src="unsafe:app//myapp/images/product-24586.png" alt="image" with='50' height='50'  />
```

I have tried the bellow fix, but no luck

```html
var myModule = angular.module('myApp', [...], function($compileProvider) {
    ...
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|chrome-extension):|data:image\//);
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|chrome-extension):/);
});
```

Comment: you are using relative url. you expression in config contains and all while..try  `$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist('/^\s/img\//');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node-webkit provides app protocol. which according to [documentation](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/App-protocol) is treated as local file protocol.
So you have to whitelist your app protocol.

`var myModule = angular.module('myApp', [...], function($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist('app://');
   });`